# Netty Thread Execution - MemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, event-handling, threadpool, netty

In the documentation of memoryawarethreadpoolexecutor

http://docs.jboss.org/netty/3.2/api/org/jboss/netty/handler/execution/MemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutor.html

Under Event execution order he mentions that

Thread X: --- Channel A (Event 2) --- Channel A (Event 1) --------------------------->

Thread Y: --- Channel A (Event 3) --- Channel B (Event 2) --- Channel B (Event 3) --->

Thread Z: --- Channel B (Event 1) --- Channel B (Event 4) --- Channel A (Event 4) --->

How can Channel A ( Event 1 , Event 2 ) , Channel A (Event 3) can be handled by two threads X , Y .

As per my  understanding single netty worker thread can do processing for many clients , but  for a client all its events( 1 ,2 3) must be handled by same worker thread right ? How can it change .

Answer (score 1):

Note that in this case the events are no longer processed by the pool of Netty Worker Threads.   Events are handed over to another pool of threads, and there is no guarantee of when a task will be executed, even for the same channel. Channel A may hand over Event 1 which is assigned to Thread X, which is preempted, then Channel A hands over Event 2 which is immediately executed by Thread Y, after which Thread X kicks in again and executes Event 1.

However, I agree that the timeline for Thread X in the graph is strange, since it would naturally pick tasks from the internal queue in order. But, and I speculate, no guarantee can be made about the the ordering of tasks queued within the ThreadPoolExecutor. Queues are normally FIFO, but they do not have to be.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly.. The same "thread per Channel" may not true anymore as soon as a ExecutorHandler will be used.